# How to assign multiple values to a single user in an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two set of array filled with values. One is two times the size of the other. I need to assign multiple set of values to a single user present in other array using PHP.

I am explaining the scenario below:

```
$user=['Raj','Rahul','Scot','Virat'];

$value=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8']
```

Here, I need to assign 2 values of `$value` array to each user in a loop. The output should be like this:

```
'Raj'->1,2
'Rahul'->3,4
'Scot'->5,6
'Virat'->7,8
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this

```
if ( count($value) !== (2*count($user) ) {
    print 'incorrect size';
}
else {
    $result = array(),
    for ($i=0, $j=0 ; $i<count($user) ; $i++, $j+=2) {
        $result[$user[$i]] = sprintf('%s,%s', $value[$j], $value[$j+1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
$user=['Raj','Rahul','Scot','Virat'];
$value=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8'];

$output = [];
foreach($user as $key => $name){
   $output[$name] = [$value[$key*2], $value[$key*2 + 1]];
}
print_r($output); // <-- you will have here your array.
```

Comment: its throwing many syntax error in each line.and also according to the user input the values should assign to user.

Comment: first it should be `$user=array('Raj','Rahul','Scot','Virat');` and also this line  `$output[$name] = [$value[$key*2], $value[$key*2 + 1]];` throwing error.

Comment: @subhra, what version of php are you using? for a modern one, this code is correct

Comment: @subhra As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax, which replaces array() with [].

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `array_chunk` and `array_walk` like as follows

```
$result = [];
$chunked_array = array_chunk($value, 2);
array_walk($chunked_array,function($v,$k) use (&$result,$user) {
    $result[$user[$k]] = implode(',',$v);
});
print_r($result);
```

Or you can simply use `for` loop like as

```
$result = [];
$count = count($value);
$j = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i += 2){
    if(isset($user[$j]))
        $result[$user[$j++]] = $value[$i].",".$value[$i+1];
}
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$user=['Raj','Rahul','Scot','Virat'];
$value=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8'];

$output = [];
foreach($user as $key => $name){
 $output[$name] = $value[$key*2].",". $value[$key*2 + 1];
 }
echo "<pre>";
print_r($output);
```

Comment: Add a few more lines to talk about your approach and how it is useful to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
$user = ['Raj','Rahul','Scot','Virat'];
$values = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8'];
$final = array();
foreach($user as $key => $content ){
    $final[$content] = array($values[$key*2],$values[($key*2)+1]);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

If the result needs to be a multidimensional array then simply combine the users and chunked values:

```
$result = array_combine($user, array_chunk($value, 2));
```

If it needs to be a comma separated list then do the same except map `implode()` to each inner array:

```
$result = array_combine($user,
                        array_map(function($v) { return implode(',', $v); },
                                  array_chunk($value, 2)));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this -

```
$user=['Raj','Rahul','Scot','Virat'];

$value=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8'];

## generate , separated values from every 2 elements in $value array
$temp = array_chunk($value, 2); // Generate array chunks with 2 elements in the same order
$temp = array_map(function($v) {
    return implode(',', $v); // implode them with comma
}, $temp);

## Combine the user array (as key) && generated $temp array (as values)
$new = array_combine($user, $temp);

var_dump($new);
```

**Output**

```
array(4) {
  ["Raj"]=>
  string(3) "1,2"
  ["Rahul"]=>
  string(3) "3,4"
  ["Scot"]=>
  string(3) "5,6"
  ["Virat"]=>
  string(3) "7,8"
}
```

If you don't need the `,` separated values, the `array_map` function can be replaced with `array_chunk($value, 2)`.

[Fiddle](https://eval.in/547903)